# Como gerar parâmetros query/GET em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, query, parâmetros, get, automatização

Eu tenho uma situação onde vou efetuar uma requisição AJAX (assíncrona) com muitas variáveis e valores passados via parâmetro GET.

Segue o código da maneira que eu gostaria que ficasse:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "www.meusite.pt" + funcao_gera_parametros({var: "valor", "var2": "valor 2"}),
    success: function(){
           //do something
    }
});
```

Qual seria a maneira mais apropriada para gerar parâmetros GET com um array `{key: "valor"}` através de uma função JavaScript que auxilie na automatização desta tarefa?

Se houver alguma solução jQuery será bem-vinda, também preciso que o código seja re-utilizável e rápido pois isso será usado na estrutura do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de uma função para isso, o ajax da jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) que você está utilizando oferece outros atributos além dos atributos url e success, você pode usar o atributo data, conforme abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "www.meusite.pt",
    data: {var: "valor", var2: "valor 2"}, // ou $('#meuForm').serialize();
    success: function() {
       // do something
    }
});
```